# If statement test on FDQuery,FieldListDef doesnt work

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

```
if (FDQuery.FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name <> 'TKey') and (FDQuery.FieldByName(FDQuery.FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name).AsString <> '') then
  begin
    .......
  end
```

I are migrating code from NexusDB to using MySql.

The table in question has data in it as this line works

```
a := FDQuery.FieldByName('Employee').AsString;
```

The if statement above worked fine using TnxTable.

This portion of the statement works "FDQuery.FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name" as the field names tick over in the loop. however the data in the field does not get read.

What am I doing wrong or how do I do the same thing different.

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: And what does the debugger show you if you set a breakpoint at that line and examine each part of the `if` statement?

Comment: The field name is correct. But the data in the field is incorrect.

Comment: I have established that for some reason the data is there during my create form routine but is lost when my TMS grid tile is populated.

Comment: I can't explain why your data is lost, because I can't see how your data gets there, how you're reading it in your *create form routine*, and can't make any sense of what you're trying to do with your (mis)use of `FieldDefList` and the unnecessary noise in your `if` statement. Use a single string variable, assign `FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name` to that string variable by reading it once, and use that variable in the `if` statement. What happens then with that much cleaner (and easier to debug) code?

Comment: Copy of code in my Create form routine

Comment: procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  it: TTMSFMXTile;
  List: TTMSFMXListView;
  Note: string;
begin
  with EmpList do
  begin
    EmpList.Visible := True;
    Columns := FDEmployee.RecordCount;
    Rows := 1;
    FDEmployee.First;
    while not FDEmployee.Eof do
    begin

Comment: it := Tiles.Add;
      it.StyleLookup := '[custom]defaulttile1';
      it.Badge := FDEmployee.FieldByName('Employee').AsString;
      it.Caption := FDEmployee.FieldByName('SName').AsString + ', ' + FDEmployee.FieldByName('FName').AsString;
      it.DetailSizePercentage := 30;
      it.Tag := FDEmployee.FieldByName('TKey').AsInteger;
      FDEmployee.Next;
    end;
    EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

Comment: with FDEmployee do
    begin
      First;
      while ((FIelds.FieldByName('TKey').AsInteger <> ATile.Tag) and (not Eof)) do
        Next;
      for I := 0 to FDEmployee.FieldDefList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        FieldName := FDEmployee.FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name;
        if (FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name <> 'TKey') and
           (Fields.FieldByName(FieldName).AsString <> '') then
        begin
          case StringToCaseSelect(FieldDefList.FieldDefs[i].Name, ['Emplyee',

Comment: Last bit of code is code Im having issues with. What I are trying to do is added lines to a list if the field has data in it. And testing field names to add pre determined comments in the fields. ie I dont want a heap of empty lines because there is no data in the fields.

Comment: Don't put code in  comments. Please [edit] the question and put the information there, where it can be easily seen and can be formatted properly.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting solution. My question is still why cant I use the original query.

I Created a FDQuery inside the tile display routine and looped through with my original code and it works fine.

Then destroyed the Query at the end of the routine.